# Splice within for loop not removing selected indexes

Tags: javascript, splice, todo

If page reloaded, splice method returned [0]{'C'}  instead of 0:{'B'}

```js
todos = [0:{"title":"A"}, 1:{"title":"B"}, 2:{"title":"C"}] //store todos - localStorage
deletedTodo = [0,2] // remove A & C from todos - store removed element index - localStorage
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  clearTodo();
});
```

function for checking deleted indexes that should removed from todos object then return updated todos object
otherwise return display Todos()

```js
function clearTodo() {
  if (
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")) &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")).length > 0
  ) {
    for (
      let index = 0;
      index <= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")).length;
      index++
    ) {
      todos.splice(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo"))[index], 1);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));

    localStorage.setItem("deletedTodo", JSON.stringify([]));
    deletedIndexex = [];

    return displayTodos();
  } else {
    return displayTodos();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your loop uses the length of the array *as fetched from local storage* as the limit, but the loop does not update local storage. You shouldn't do that; get the array from local storage into a local variable. Do the splicing as necessary to the local array, and then save it back.

Comment: 1. Look carefully at the todos array, you are defining the index within the array. That is not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: @mplungjan Don't think that matters if the problem here is valid.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Yes it does: [how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @mplungjan I am aware of that post, and I believe there is no problem in asking homework questions if the problem mentioned is valid and the question is on-topic. Unless there is an official statement made against it in the rules, I don't see much problem. Or is there anything specific problem in this question that you are trying to point to that I am unable to conceive correctly?

Comment: 1. It is fairly obvious that it is a homework question 2. when it is, we should be aware of posting full solutions. It was just a comment and not meant to have OP delete the question because it was homework or something. Of course you can ask homework questions, but it is generally good to see the actual tasks on task form. Or perhaps the teacher is just poor in asking questions.

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, that makes sense. I had the incorrect impression from your previous comments that you might want this question removed due to it possibly being a homework one. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: its not homework ! i am practicing JavaScript based on UI animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read localStorage once and write in only one place each.
2. Stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

For example

```js
const todoObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo") || '{"todos":[], "deletedTodos":[] }')
let deletedTodos = todoObject.deletedTodos;
let todos = todoObject.todos;
const writeLocal = () => localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoObject));
function clearTodo() {
  if (deletedTodos.length === 0) return; // nothing to do here
  deletedTodos.forEach(index => todos.splice(index, 1));
  todoObject.todos = todos;
  todoObject.deletedTodos = [];
  writeLocal();
  displayTodos();
}
function addTodo(str) {
  todos.push({ "desc":str, "time": new Date().getTime() }); 
  writeLocal();
  displayTodos();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second line's, `todoObject.deletedTodos;` give some sort of type error in case the `todoObject` is not really an object but a string because it is a localstorage value (string only afaik)?

Comment: No, since it is not a string: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo") || '{"todos":[], "deletedTodos":[] }')` - either it is a filled parsed object from localStorage or a parsed object with empty arrays if there is no todo stringified  in the localStorage

Comment: The `||` tests if there is a todo in localstorage. If yes, it is parsed otherwise the stringified default object is parsed

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense! 

Answer (score 2):

When you splice you should decrease your index by number of deleted items since the array got shorter. To behave your array normally load it from the local storage only once. And since you splice a different array, just filter it:

```
function clearTodo() {
  const deletedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo"));
  if (deletedTodos?.length) {
    todos = todos.filter((_, i) => !deletedTodos.includes(i));
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    localStorage.setItem("deletedTodo", JSON.stringify([]));
    deletedIndexex = [];
  }
  return displayTodos();

}
```

Comment: @mplungjan a nice note

Comment: `return displayTodos(); } else { return displayTodos(); }` is the same as 
`} return displayTodos(); }`

Comment: Yes you could just remove the else and have one return statement

Comment: @JuniusL was trying to address only the OP's question 

Comment: @Alexander Nenashev thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified code:

```
function clearTodo() {
  if (
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")) &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")).length > 0
  ) {
    const deletedIndexes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedTodo")).sort((a, b) => b - a);
    for (let i = 0; i < deletedIndexes.length; i++) {
      todos.splice(deletedIndexes[i], 1);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    localStorage.setItem("deletedTodo", JSON.stringify([]));
    return displayTodos();
  } else {
    return displayTodos();
  }
}
```